# Proving an equality of functors in algebraic theories

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra, yoneda-lemma

Can somebody explain how are they claiming the following highlighted identity in the book *Algebraic Theories* by Vitale?
[image]

The reason I am confused is because the image of the $F$ functor lands inside $\mathcal{B}$ whereas the image of the $\mathcal{B}(-, FX)$ functor lands inside the category whose objects are morphism classes in $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: I'm not sure why $\mathcal B(-,FX)$ is brought into the picture, especially that we want to evaluate the colimit specifically in $\mathcal B$, it was meant probably an implicit computation method for the colimit, and then we need to take the representing object. Nevertheless, you can directly prove the claim by observing that $(X,1_X)$ is a *terminal object* in $El\,Y_{\mathcal C^{op}}(X)$.

Comment: @Berci Yes I was able to prove the claim in that manner, just wasn't sure how is that equality written. Might just be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly is just a misprint.
After removing the '$={\cal B}(-,FX)$' part one obtains

'[...] because for $A=Y_{{\cal C}^{op}}(X)={\cal C}(-,X)$, a colimit of $F\cdot\Phi_A$ is $FX$'

which makes perfect sense (cf. Berci's comment)